# Routing API with waypoint optimisation

Tags: openstreetmap, routing, api

Is there any *free* OSM Routing REST API without limits which supports multiple waypoints between the start point and destination AND is able to optimize these waypoints instead of calculating a route in the given order?
I've only found [MapQuest](https://developer.mapquest.com/products/directions/) which is limited by 500 Requests/day.

I know that a [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87935/do-you-know-a-service-route-calculation-to-get-a-route-between-several-points) has been asked 2 years ago but maybe there is an API now.

Comment: You won't find 'unlimited' & 'free'. That does not make sense if you think about it. It is like asking for unlimited money for doing nothing.

Comment: Actually there are Routing APIs for non-commercial projecs which support unlimited requests without registration. The only issue I have with them is that none of the ones I found supported waypoint optimisation. BTW, my project is for academic purpose. Thats why it should be free.

Comment: Maybe they say this. But I'm pretty sure they have to ban you if you interpret their 'unlimited' too big ;). Also academic does not mean it has to be free IMO, research can get grants.

Comment: I just want to mention https://www.routexl.com which is also based on OSM data.